# Can I know the issue of this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

[image]

but I'm getting an error:

[image]

If I remove the comma-separated value from the variable, it is working fine. As well as if I remove the NULL checking feature it is working fine. Can I know the issue of this

Comment: Why do you post text as image? Format is as code.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because a `CASE WHEN` can only return 1 value.
And a `STRING_SPLIT` returns a resultset.

I assume something like this is what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM Facility f
WHERE (@Facility IS NULL OR f.facilityCode IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@Facility,',')))
```

This will get all records if the variable is null.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution similar to this query

Comment: See update, the OR won't do the split if the variable is null.

Answer (score 1):

The function dbo.split will split the string in more than one value. This will confuse your subquery and the error you are receiving will be thrown.

In case you need what goes before the comma consider using:

```
select top 1 value 
from dbo.split(@Facility, ','))
```

Comment: Aleks, I dont need to select top 1 value. I need to return all values from the split function

Comment: You can try something not as beautiful as you did when you first check if the value is null then execute the sql. More like: IF @ Facility is not null then do your both cases in the if and the else clause.


IF @ Facility is not null
       // your split case 
ELSE 
       // the other version

Answer (score 0):

You want to say if the variable is NULL so ignore the WHERE statement, if so your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Facility f
WHERE @Facility IN (select value from dbo.split(@Facility, ',')) OR @Facility IS NULL
```